# Howw to reshape X and Y from (300, 1000,50) to (300000, 50)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a dataset:

```
X.shape = (300, 1000, 50)
Y.shape = (300,)
```

- Y is the true values (4 options: [0..3])

I want to reshape X to: `(300000, 50)` and Y to `(300000,)`

- The new `X.shape` will be `[X.shape[0]*X.shape[1], X.shape[2]]`
- The new `Y.shape` will be `[X.shape[0]*X.shape[1],]` and it will contain the right duplicate values of `Y` (according to the new shape).

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried using `numpy.reshape` ?

Comment: reshape won't handle the Y with the correct values

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
X = X.reshape(-1, Y.shape[-1])
```

However, it becomes unclear how to broadcast the arrays then, since broadcasting aligns to the right (implicitly prepends unit dimensions, not appends).

You could repeat the elements of `Y`:

```
Y = np.repeat(Y, 1000)
```

or the entire array itself:

```
Y = np.tile(Y, 4)
```

Both are overkill.

Just use proper broadcasting instead:

```
# X untouched
Y = Y[:, None, None]
```

Or equivalently

```
Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1, 1)
```